# Running macro on multiple sheets at same time

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks and each contains workbook open event code stored in "this workbook":

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Module4.macro_timer
End Sub
```

code stored in module 4:

```
Public interval As Double

Sub macro_timer()
    interval = Now + TimeValue("00:03:00")
    Application.OnTime interval, "my_macro"
End Sub

Sub my_macro()
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).refreshall
    Call macro_timer
End Sub
```

All the opened workbooks have the same code.

When I open those workbooks at same time, this code should run in parallel. When I open one workbook it works, but when I open more than one workbook it is not working at all.

Comment: I think that when you mean worksheets its workbooks, right? You can't run multiple macros at once, not on the same instance of excel. So you should create a workbook which will open all your workbooks in new instances each.

Comment: yes, you were right, and I got your point, thx buddy.

Comment: I guess above code should work

Comment: Edit your question to add the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58851175/edit). Comments are not for code.

Comment: ohk, I have deleted it. sorry for issue

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` is the same as `Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).refreshall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this for a colleague of mine with the same situation as yours:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()

    Dim MyPaths As Variant
    Dim MyFiles As Variant
    MyPaths = Array("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Excel\", _
        "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Excel\", _
        "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Excel\", _
        "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Excel\")
    MyFiles = Array("Tiempos.xlsx", "Tiempos.xlsx", "Tiempos.xlsx", "Tiempos.xlsx")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    For i = LBound(MyPaths) To UBound(MyPaths)
        MyPath = MyPaths(i)
        MyFile = MyFiles(i)
        NewInstance MyPath, MyFile
    Next i

End Sub
Sub NewInstance(Path As String, File As String)

    Dim exApp As Excel.Application
    Set exApp = New Excel.Application

    exApp.Workbooks.Open Path & File
    exApp.Visible = True

End Sub
```

You only need to edit the `MyPaths` and `MyFiles` arrays with your own paths and filenames.

Comment: I have a question that, how name of all the workbooks can be same? and even if it can be same can we open all these on same time??

Comment: I guess for example you have taken all name same am i right?

Comment: Yes, of course, each of them is open in a different instance. Thought only the first one will be able to save, the rest of them will be read only. But this is just an example, you can edit the names and paths to your own.

Comment: ohk, it was quite silly question asked by me I know, but thx for reply.

Comment: @Arshitpatel if it helped, please don't forget to accept this as an answer :)

Comment: there is compiler error stating that "variable not defined" indicates for "Rutas" in code

Comment: @Arshitpatel sorry, I've translated the code but not the whole... Check my edit.

Comment: do you have vba code that closes all open workbook with the use of above mentioned code by you? if yes, pls let me know, because it's not closing simply by normal code. thq.

Comment: The code won't close the new workbooks because they are on different instances and can't control them. I'd recommend to write some code on these to close them when finished @Arshitpatel